# Modelling random effects as an autoregressive-autoregressive process

Tags: time-series, arima, laplace-approximation

Has anyone ever come across an autoregressive-autogressive process.
I am modelling positively correlated time-series of random effects in a fisheries model.  They are integrated out via the Laplace approximation.
An ar(1) process is attractive due to the simple calculations which can be optimized.  However for some data the model always wants to set the correlation to 1.0 or the upper bound.  I think this is because for an ar(1) process the correlation declines too quickly.  So a "longer memory" process may be indicated.  One way I have thought of to do this is to model the random effects as an ar(1) process based on a set of random variables which are themselves derived from an ar(1) process.   This leads to a set of RV's for which the autocorrelation dies much more slowly and the entire scheme is based on only one parameter.  The only extra complication is that since the RV's for the second ar(1) process are not uncorrelated one needs to normalize the variance to 1 by dividing by an expression which depends on the correlation. This results in the resulting process as being slightly non stationary, although it appears to converge quickly. I figure that if this is a good idea it must already be done, but I can't find any references.  Any advice would be welcomed.

Here is a simple example.  Suppose the first ar(1) process has autocorrelation parameter -0.5 and the second process has autocorrelation parameter 0.92 so that  $$y_1=\epsilon_1 \hbox{ and } y_i=-0.5y_{i-1}+\sqrt{0.75}\epsilon_i$$
Then setting 
 $$x_1=y_1 \hbox{ and } x_i=\frac{0.92x_{i-1}+\sqrt{1-0.92^2}y_i}{\gamma_i}$$ 
where the $\gamma_i$ are chosen so that the variance of the $x_i=1$,

one obtains the variance-covariance matrix for the $x_i$ like this

```
1.00  0.91  0.92  0.86  0.85  0.82  0.80  0.77  0.75  0.73
0.91  1.00  0.92  0.91  0.88  0.86  0.83  0.80  0.78  0.76
0.92  0.92  1.00  0.91  0.91  0.87  0.85  0.82  0.80  0.77
0.86  0.91  0.91  1.00  0.91  0.91  0.87  0.85  0.82  0.80
0.85  0.88  0.91  0.91  1.00  0.91  0.91  0.87  0.85  0.82
0.82  0.86  0.87  0.91  0.91  1.00  0.91  0.91  0.87  0.85
0.80  0.83  0.85  0.87  0.91  0.91  1.00  0.91  0.91  0.87
0.77  0.80  0.82  0.85  0.87  0.91  0.91  1.00  0.91  0.91
0.75  0.78  0.80  0.82  0.85  0.87  0.91  0.91  1.00  0.91
0.73  0.76  0.77  0.80  0.82  0.85  0.87  0.91  0.91  1.00
```

So the autocorrelation has much more persistence than that for an ar(1) process with correlation 0.91.

After some thought I realized that the point of this construction is not that if you iterate it p times you get an stationary ar(p) process.
Rather it is that it produces a nice way to parametrize ar(p) processes.
Thus it is a stable way to parametrize the correlation matrices associated with an ar(p) processes which can be used in maximum likelihood estimation or in my case using ar(p) distributed random effects in nonlinear models.

So my question really is whether or not there is already a stable method for parametrizing these correlation matrices.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is only one way of constructing an AR(2) process. Let $B$ denote the backshift operator.  Your first equation can be written 
$$
(1 + 0.5B)y_i = \epsilon_i  \tag{1}
$$
where $\epsilon_i$ is white noise. Your second equation says that
$$
(1-0.92B)x_i = c y_i \tag{2}.
$$
Applying $(1 + 0.5B)$ to both sides of (2) yields
$$
(1+0.5B)(1-0.92B)x_i = c(1+0.5B)y_i = c\epsilon_i
$$
which shows that $x_i$ is simply an AR(2) process.

The autocovariance $\gamma_k$ satisisfies the difference equation $(1+0.5B)(1-0.92B)\gamma_k=0$ with solution on the form $\gamma_k = b_1 (-0.5)^k + b_2 0.92^k$ so asymptotically the persistence of the autocovariance function is identical to that of the "slowest" AR(1) process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Of interest here is not really the asymptotic behaviour, but rather the immediate behaviour. Typically one is fitting a model with 10-100 categories and so that will be the number of positively correlated random effects.

Answer (score 0):

I determined the answer to my problem. It is sort of interesting so I thought I would sketch the ideas here.  First the problem.  In natural resource management one often fits models to age or length data where the errors in the data are highly positively autocorrelated.  Assume that a subset of the data  are being fitted with a number of  multinomial log-likelihoods.  To account for the positive autocorrelation one wants to include positively autcorrelated random effects. Let $p_i$ be the predicted proportion for the $i$'th bin.
The random effects are included as

$$q_i=\frac{p_i\exp(\epsilon_i)}{\sum_j p_j\exp(\epsilon_j)}$$

so thaty the $q_i$ are the new predicted proportions in the model.
The denominator is included to that the $q_i$ will sum to 1.
If $\bar  \epsilon$  is the mean of the $\epsilon_i$ this can be written as
$$q_i=\frac{p_i\exp(\epsilon_i-\bar\epsilon)}{\sum_j p_j\exp(\epsilon_j-\bar\epsilon)}$$

Subtracting off the sample mean reduces the autocorrelation.  In fact if the autocorrelation dies off slowly it is impossible to create random effects with high enough lag 1 autocorrelation.  So one want to use a method to parameterize the random effects so that the lag one autocorrelation is high, but dies off more quickly than those fo ar(1) process.  It turns out that autoregressive-autoregressive processes are a convenient way to parameterize these random effects.  Let $i$ index the components of a time series and for $k=1,\ldots$ let $k$ index the order of the autoregressive-autoregressive process so that

$$x_{ki}=\frac{\alpha x_{k,i-1}+ \sqrt{1-\alpha^2} x_{k-1,i}}{\lambda_k} $$
where the $x_{0i}$ are standard normal and the $\lambda_k$ are chosen so that the variance of the time series is 1. By construction $\lambda_1=1$. The autocorrelation is determined by the single parameter $\alpha$. For $\alpha=0.9$ and a fourth order process the correlation matrix is

```
1         0.993956  0.976318  0.948365  0.911855
0.993956  1         0.993956  0.976318  0.948365
0.976318  0.993956  1         0.993956  0.976318
0.948365  0.976318  0.993956  1         0.993956
0.911855  0.948365  0.976318  0.993956  1
```

One sees how much more quickly it dies off compared to an ar(1) process with the same lag one autocorrelation.

From the cholesky decomposition of the inverse of this matrix one can calculate the coefficients of the corresponding fourth order aurotregressive process.

$$y_i = 2.96923y_{i-1} - 3.28944y_{i-2} + 1.6125y_{i-3} - 0.295267y_{i-4}  
   + 0.0162462\epsilon_i$$

The element of the correlation matrix which are needed for parameter estimation can be calculated by solving a nonlinear system of equations.

Anyway that is the idea.  I have incorporated these calculation into a large nonlinear statistical model for analyzing commercial fisheries data.